# TranslateAnimation cuts of Image outside of Imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I am using TranslateAnimation to center my image after it has been moved, the problem is if part of the image is outside of the view when the animation starts it will not be visible during the animation:

My code:

```
        TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, deltaX, 0,
                deltaY);
        trans.setDuration(250);
        trans.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
        this.startAnimation(trans);
```

**Edit:**

Solved it by first centering the image and then drawing the animation from its original position to the center as follows:

```
        setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        //A void that centers the image inside the view
        center(true, true);
        TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(-deltaX, 0,-deltaY, 0);
        trans.setDuration(250);
        trans.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
        this.startAnimation(trans);
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding android doesn't draw a portion of a view that is not visible on the screen. When apply animations to a view, only the pixels are shifted while the view remains in the old position which should be the problem as only the visible pixels of your image are only shifted.

My idea is to add a animation listener and overide the animationStart method and add the view manually to the corrent posistion or you can also try this before you call the start animation.
This might work.